# mathml to latex conversion using mml2tex(XSLT)

Tags: xslt, latex, mathml

I am trying to convert MathML to LaTex using XSLT with the templates available in https://github.com/transpect/mml2tex. This is working fine for MathML with the namespace. But the same not working without namespace.

### without namespace

```
input: <math display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>
output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><math display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>
```

### with namespace

```
input: <mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mml:mi>a</mml:mi></mml:math>
output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mml2tex a?>
```

### with namespace declaration

```
input:<math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>

output:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>
```

Comment: Well, if an XML vocabulory puts its elements into a namespace then to distinguish them from any other vocabulories and even if you don't use an explicit prefix then I would guess that you at least need a default declaration `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">...</math>` to technically use MathML and not to use elements that might have the same local name as elements from the MathML vocabulory but are in no namespace with a predefined and recognized semantics. So why do you have input that you believe is MathML without the appropriate namespace? Can you fix the input generation?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried and updated the output. 

input:<math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>

output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>

Comment: So which is the MathML input you have (or do you have all those variations) and which is the LaTex output (or mix of XML with LaTex in processing instructions?) you expect? Which of the various ways to use that library of stylesheets have you used exactly?

Comment: I am comfortable with any one of the following inputs(without mml:). 

input: <math display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>
input: <math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>. The output should be LaTex(with or without processing instruction) without MathML.

Comment: I am converting using saxon.jar(java -jar saxon9.jar -o out.tex math.mml /xsl/invoke-mml2tex.xsl).

Comment: In my understanding you would (need to) use either `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math>` or `<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mml:mi>a</mml:mi></mml:math>` to have MathML input to be transformed by the stylesheet, any elements not in the MathML namespace are not transformed.

Comment: To put it shortly, if your input is not in the namespace (or in general, the schema) expected by the stylesheet, then you have to either modify the stylseheet or pre-transform the input to put it in the expected  namespace (or schema).

Comment: @Martin Honnen You are correct. Thanks for the reply I forgot to remove the mml: in the declaration xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML".<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block"><mi>a</mi></math> this works fine.

Comment: @michael Thanks for your reply.